# How to append TEMPLATE Element to shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html-templates

When I try to append template to the shadow DOM, it only shows as a "#documentFragment", and never renders or copies the actual elements structured within the template.

I spent hours trying to figure it out. The solution I found was to use:

- template.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);

instead of:

- template.content.cloneNode(true);

then, and only then, everything works as expected.

My question is, am I doing something wrong?

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
const form = document.createElement('form');
const gateway = document.createElement('fieldset');
const legend = document.createElement('legend');
gateway.appendChild(legend);
const username = document.createElement('input');
username.setAttribute('type', 'email');
username.setAttribute('name', 'username');
username.setAttribute('placeholder', 'email@address.com');
username.setAttribute('id', 'username');
gateway.appendChild(username);
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
button.innerHTML = 'Next';
gateway.appendChild(button);
form.appendChild(gateway);
template.appendChild(form);
class UserAccount extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowDOM = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const clone = template.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    // This does not work
    // const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    shadowDOM.appendChild(clone);
    shadowDOM.querySelector('legend').innerHTML = this.getAttribute('api');
  }
}
window.customElements.define('user-account', UserAccount);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"> -->
  <script src="./js/user-account.js" defer></script>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <user-account api="/accounts"></user-account>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TEMPLATES` are only interesting if you need to make multiple copies or want to work in plain HTML + CSS as much as possible.

Many Web Components show the usage:

```
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = "Hello World"
```

and then do:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
```

Which, because the template is only used as a single "parent" container, you can write as:

```
constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).innerHTML = "Hello World";
  }
```

Note: `super()` returns `this`, and `attachShadow()` *sets* and *returns* `this.shadowRoot` ... for free

### Two types of TEMPLATES

You can create a `<TEMPLATE>` in **DOM**, or you can create a `template` in **Memory**

#### Templates in Memory

9 out of 10 **Memory-templates** can be done with other HTMLElements as container,
as is the case with your code, where `FORM` can be the main container. No need for a `template` container.

If you do build a template in memory, learn the value of [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) over
(the often misused) [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

In Memory templates are great for making (many) alterations (with code)

#### Templates in DOM

No need for trying to stuff **HTML** and **CSS** in JavaScript strings, you have a DOM in the HTML document!
Use the [`<TEMPLATE>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) HTML Element.

Add shadowDOM [`<slot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots) to the mix and you will spent less time debugging JavaScript and more time writing semantic HTML.

DOM Templates are great for easy HTML and CSS editting (in your IDE with syntax highlighting) of more static HTML/CSS structures

---

Here are both types of TEMPLATES with your code, which one is easier for a developer?

```js
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  const gateway = document.createElement('fieldset');
  const legend = document.createElement('legend');
  const username = document.createElement('input');
  username.setAttribute('type', 'email');
  username.setAttribute('name', 'username');
  username.setAttribute('placeholder', 'email@address.com');
  username.setAttribute('id', 'username');
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  button.innerHTML = 'Next';
  gateway.append(legend,username,button);
  form.appendChild(gateway);
  
  class Form extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(element) {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'}).append(element);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('legend').innerHTML = this.getAttribute('api');
    }
  }
  
  window.customElements.define('form-one', class extends Form {
    constructor() {
      super(form)
    }
  });
  window.customElements.define('form-two', class extends Form {
    constructor() {
      super(document.getElementById("FormTwo").content);
    }
  });
```

```html
<template id="FormTwo">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend></legend>
      <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="email@address.com" id="username">
      <button type="button">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</template>

<form-one api="/accounts"></form-one>
<form-two api="/accounts"></form-two>
```

Note:

In the above code the `<TEMPLATE>.content` is **moved** to shadowDOM.

To re-use (clone) the `<TEMPLATE>` the code must be:

`super(document.getElementById("FormTwo").content.cloneNode(true));`

### Why your `template.content` failed

Your code failed because with

```
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  const form = document.createElement("form");
  template.appendChild(form);
```

`template` has **no** content

`TEMPLATE` isn't a regular HTMLElement, **you have to append to `.content`**

```
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  const form = document.createElement("form");
  template.content.appendChild(form);
```

will work

Most Web Component examples show:

```
  const template = document.createElement("template");
  template.innerHTML = "Hello World"
```

`innerHTML` sets `.content` *under the hood*

Which explains why instead of:

`template.content.appendChild(form);`

you can write:

`template.innerHTML = form.outerHTML;`

Comment: I've learned so much from your answer. I'll keep studying it to get the most out of it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A 'template' element is a special element that doesn't actually render right away([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)). This is why appending the template produces nothing.

`template.firstElementChild.cloneNode` means "get the child of the template (i.e. the form) and clone it", which is the same as just appending the form, which works (below).

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
const form = document.createElement('form');
const gateway = document.createElement('fieldset');
const legend = document.createElement('legend');
gateway.appendChild(legend);
const username = document.createElement('input');
username.setAttribute('type', 'email');
username.setAttribute('name', 'username');
username.setAttribute('placeholder', 'email@address.com');
username.setAttribute('id', 'username');
gateway.appendChild(username);
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
button.innerHTML = 'Next';
gateway.appendChild(button);
form.appendChild(gateway);
template.appendChild(form);
class UserAccount extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowDOM = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    shadowDOM.appendChild(form);
    shadowDOM.querySelector('legend').innerHTML = this.getAttribute('api');
  }
}

window.customElements.define('user-account', UserAccount);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"> -->
  <script src="./js/user-account.js" defer></script>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <user-account api="/accounts"></user-account>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does that not defeat the purpose of using a template for the web-component?